# Correct way to add links in an SVG image

Tags: html, css, svg

If I have an SVG image and I want to make it interactive by adding some links, is right to do it this way?

```
<a href="https://www.link-1.com">
 <g>
 </g>
</a>

<a href="https://www.link-2.com">
 <g>
 </g>
</a>
```

So wrapping the `<g>` tag with an `<a>` tag? Or there is another best practice?

Comment: Please share more details. What do you want to achieve? Where are you stuck?

Comment: What does the <g> tag add?

Answer (score 1):

Your example is the correct way to add links to SVG.

> SVG's `<a>` element is a container, which means you can create a link
> around text (like in HTML) but also around any shape.

**Example:**

```html
<a href="/docs/Web/SVG/Element/circle">
    <circle cx="50" cy="40" r="35" />
</a>
```

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/a